# Is number of tasks same as the number of fits for GridSearchCV Logistic Regression?

Tags: logistic-regression, kaggle, gridsearchcv

I am training a Logistic Regression model with GridSearchCV. The log says:

**Fitting 3 folds for each of 1600 candidates, totalling 4800 fits**

Further, for tasks below line in printed in log:

**[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  42 tasks      | elapsed:  2.9min**

Is the number of tasks here(like 42 tasks as above) same as the number of fits(=4800)?

I want to estimate the time taken to finish the training?

Answer (score 0):

Deciphering it step by step

**Fitting 3 folds for each of 1600 candidates, totaling 4800 fits**

1. **1600 candidates** means you are trying out 1600 **combinations**
2. **Fitting 3 folds** means you specified cv=**3**, you are cross-validating **3** times on training data.
3. **totaling 4800 fits** = **1600** * **3**. i.e we have **4800 tasks**

**[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 42 tasks | elapsed: 2.9min**

1. **Parallel(n_jobs=-1)**, **-1** means you are running on all cores of your CPU
2. **Done 42 tasks** meand out of **4800**, **42** fits have been completed
3. **elapsed: 2.9min** - from the time execution started it took **2.9min** for completing **42** fits/ **42** training

Let me know if you still have any doubts.